# Looping through filenames in bashscript - need to update a line of text in a file on each loop nth iteration with n+1 but loop sequence casues issue

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to pad a series of wav files with silence at the beginning and end using ffmpeg.

the line of code for this i gleaned from elsewhere on this amazing site:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy output.wav
```

where input.txt is simply a list of 3 filenames:
silence.wav
0.wav
silence.wav

indicating what is to be concatenated

I can do this for an individual file and then update line 2 manually, but there are 1000+ files. They are named 0.wav 1.wav 2.wav.

I figure this is trivial in a loop:

```
COUNTER=1
for FILE in *.wav
do
        ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy $FILE
        echo $FILE
        echo $COUNTER
        sed -i "2s/.*/file \'${COUNTER}.wav\'/" input.txt
        ((COUNTER=COUNTER+1))
done
```

However the loop doesn't iterate sequentially 0.wav 1.wav 2.wav - rather more erratically (0.wav, 10.wav, 11.wav) - so my counter is out of sync. and my saved filenames are not aligned with their original filenames.

Is there a work around that strips the name from the file itself rather than relying on a counter?

Comment: The filename expansion sorts lexicographically (e.g. "11" < "9"), not numerically (e.g. 11 > 9).

Comment: Also, your loop will always be out of sync, because you should edit the `input.txt` *first* (and just write `"$FILE"` there; no need to synthesize the name again from a counter) and *then* call `ffmpeg`, not vice versa. That said, if the output file is the same file as one of the input files, [it may be a problem](https://superuser.com/questions/912730/ffmpeg-batch-convert-make-same-filename). You may need to pick a different output naming.

Comment: It's not erratic, and it is in sequence. It's in *lexicographic* order, not numerical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the counter is already contained in the file name, why not just reuse the file name? That would avoid the issue with string sorting (in which `"11" < "9"`) versus numerical sorting (in which `11 > 9`) and it would also work fine if the file names (numbers) were sparse. Also, the output file should *not* be the same file as one of the inputs. (It *might* be the case that `ffmpeg` can handle it gracefully using temporary files, bu I wouldn’t bet on that.)

```sh
for file in *.wav; do
  sed -i "2s/.*/file \'${file}\'/" input.txt
  ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy "output-${file}"
  mv "output-${file}" "$file"  # replaces original file!
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your setup is that you read your files in **alphabetical order**. So after `1.wav` comes `10.wav`.

**Your code then becomes:**

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy 10.wav
sed -i "2s/.*/file \'2.wav\'/" input.txt
```

So FFmpeg works with `10.wav`, while you replace something about `2.wav` in `input.txt`. Maybe you could do something like this to loop over your files:

```
COUNTER=1
while [ $COUNTER -le 1000 ]
do
  echo "Filename: ${COUNTER}.wav"
  ((COUNTER=COUNTER+1))
done
```

I don't know if FFmpeg starts a new process, but the loop might start FFmpeg, but not wait till it is finished. This way you could end up with 1000 FFmpeg processes running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try replacing

```sh
for FILE in *.wav
```

with

```sh
for FILE in $(ls *.wav | sort -t '.' -k 1 -n)
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: [Should you parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: It does work but I'm not 100% what is happening here -> recast as list - sort list before iteration?